# How to implement return method from subclass into parentclass?

Tags: c#

I have parent class Zival from which I create subclasses odraslaZival which returns some number that user definesand in Mladic I want to get enum returned. Parent class already has a return type, how can I add return types from subclasses into parent class?

```
class Zival
{

    public Zival(string p, int s, double t, Dnevnik d, Kartoteka k)
    {
        poreklo = p;
        starost = s;
        teza = t;
        Dnevnik = d;
        Kartoteka = k;
        this.spol = spol;
    }

    public string Izpis()
    {
        return "Ime:"+this.poreklo+" Starost:"+ this.starost + " Teža:" + this.teza+"\n" + this.Dnevnik.Izpis() + this.Kartoteka.Izpis();
    }
}

class OdraslaZival : Zival
{
    int NumberOfChild;

    public OdraslaZival(string p, int s, double t, Dnevnik d, Kartoteka k, Spol spol, int NumberOfChild) : base(p, s, t, d, k)
    {
        this.NumberOfChild = NumberOfChild;
    }
}

class Mladic : Zival
{
    enum prehranjevanje { mesojedec, rastlinojedec, vsejedec}

    public Mladic(string p, int s, double t, Dnevnik d, Kartoteka k, Spol spol, int prehranjevanje) : base(p, s, t, d, k)
    {

    }
}
```

I expect that program returns: "this.poreklo + this.starost + this.teza + this.Dnevnik.Izpis() + this.Kartoteka.Izpis() + 'enum of sublcas' + 'NumberOfChild'"

Answer (score 0):

Make your print method virtual

```
public virtual string Izpis()
{
    return "Ime:"+this.poreklo+" Starost:"+ this.starost + " Teža:" + this.teza+"\n" +
        this.Dnevnik.Izpis() + this.Kartoteka.Izpis();
}
```

This allows you to override it in a descendant class.

```
class OdraslaZival : Zival
{
    int NumberOfChild;

    ...

    public override string Izpis()
    {
        return  base.Izpis() + " Number of children: " + NumberOfChild;
    }
}
```

In class `Mladic` you could write

```
public override string Izpis()
{
    return  base.Izpis() + " My enum: " + prehranjevanje;
}
```

But of course you cannot print the enum of class `Mladic` in class `OdraslaZival` as the latter has only access to members of parent classes and itself, but not to sibling classes.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you are asking about object inheritance. The child class can call base.Method() and append their data onto what is returned from the parent class. In C# inheritance flows from parent to child, not child to parent. So children can access the methods and properties of their parent, but the parent has no knowledge of their children.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bar = new Bar("Jane Doe", 25);
        Console.WriteLine(bar.Speak());
        Console.Read();
    }

}

public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Foo(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public virtual string Speak() => $"My Name is {Name}";
}

public class Bar: Foo
{
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Bar(string name, int age) : base(name)
    {
        Age = age;
    }

    public override string Speak()
    {
        return $"{base.Speak()} and my age is {Age}";
    }
}
```

That returns "My name is Jane Doe and my age is 25".